# BCP Fails to import csv into Azure SQL database table

Tags: sql-server, csv

I'm getting the error code shown far below when I run the BCP command to import a CSV to an Azure hosted SQL existing table.

- I can successfully test the connection using an ODBC user dsn from my PC
- There is no ) in my csv file
- I've tried with and without headers
- I've tried converting the csv to a tab delim file

None of these work and after an two hours searching google, I could use some help...

**BCP Command:**

bcp us_equities_price_capture in "c:\temp\dev\sql\us_equities_price_capture4.csv" -S mydbserver1.database.windows.net -d mydbinstance -U sql_user1 -P mypassword -q -c -t -h

**Error**
SQLState = 37000, NativeError = 102
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: Do you have any limitations what would stop you from using `BULK INSERT`?

Comment: Does the table have insert trigger(s) on it that may be generating this error?